# Combine values of three queries/ three fields?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to create a report which looks at:

- New orders made before 5pm
- New orders after 5pm
- Orders fulfilled same day

(Same day is classified as an order being made before 5pm and being shipped before 7pm)

The tables should be in the format of:

---

### Date - Type - Pre_5 - After_5 - Total - Same_Day

Ideally all of the information should be shown on a single line, their should be two rows for each day, one row where type = CO and another where type = DO.

Currently when running the query it returns the data with additional rows, some containing nulls.

The approaches I have already tried are:

- Simply Grouping by values
- Creating three queries and running union on results
- Sub queries for each CASE

The following code is for the query attempting to simply group.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(ORDER_ID),
  TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
  CASE
    WHEN ORDER_TYPE = 31
    THEN 'CO'
    ELSE 'DO'
  END AS "TYPE" ,
  CASE
    WHEN TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') < 17
    THEN NVL(COUNT(ORDER_ID),0)
  END AS "Pre_5",
  CASE
    WHEN TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') >= 17
    THEN NVL(COUNT(ORDER_ID),0)
  END AS "After_5",
  CASE
    WHEN TO_CHAR(shipped_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE,
      'DD/MM/YYYY')
    AND TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') < 17
     AND TO_CHAR(shipped_date, 'HH24') <= 19
    THEN COUNT(ORDER_ID)
   END AS "SAME DAY"
FROM
  ORDER_HEADER
WHERE
   CLIENT_ID       = '*****'
 AND creation_date > sysdate -7
GROUP BY
  ORDER_TYPE,
  TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
  TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24'),
  TO_CHAR(SHIPPED_DATE, 'HH24'),
  TO_CHAR(SHIPPED_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Code for Pre_5

```
SELECT
      COUNT(ORDER_ID) AS PRE_5,
      CASE
    WHEN ORDER_TYPE = 31
    THEN 'CO'
    ELSE 'DO'
  END AS "TYPE",
  TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')  
    FROM
      ORDER_HEADER
    WHERE
      TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') < 17
    AND CLIENT_ID                    ='*****'
    AND creation_date                > sysdate -7
    GROUP BY ORDER_TYPE, TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    ORDER BY TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Code for After_5

```
SELECT
      COUNT(ORDER_ID) AS AFTER_5,
      CASE
    WHEN ORDER_TYPE = 31
    THEN 'CO'
    ELSE 'DO'
  END AS "TYPE",
  TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    FROM
      ORDER_HEADER
    WHERE
      TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') >= 17
    AND CLIENT_ID                     ='*****'
    AND creation_date                 > sysdate -1
       GROUP BY ORDER_TYPE, TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    ORDER BY TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Code for Same_Day

```
SELECT
      COUNT(ORDER_ID) AS SAME_DAY,
      CASE
    WHEN ORDER_TYPE = 31
    THEN 'CO'
    ELSE 'DO'
  END AS "TYPE",
  TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    FROM
      ORDER_HEADER
    WHERE
      TO_CHAR(shipped_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) = TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE,
      'DD/MM/YYYY')
    AND TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') < 17
    AND TO_CHAR(shipped_date, 'HH24') <= 19
    AND CLIENT_ID='*****' AND creation_date > sysdate -7
           GROUP BY ORDER_TYPE, TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    ORDER BY TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Ideally I need the information from the three separate queries to be shown on one row, grouped by the date and type.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a CTE? Something like this (I removed most of code you used for those queries in order to simplify it):

```
with 
  pre_5 as
    (select count(Order_id) as pre_5, 
            type,
            creation_date
     from ...
    ),
  after_5 as
    (select count(order_id) as after_5,
            type,
            creation_date
     from ...
    ),
  same_day as
    (select count(order_id) as same_day,
            type,
            creation_date
     from ...
    )
select
  p.creation_date,
  p.type,
  sum(p.pre_5)    pre_5,
  sum(a.after_5)  after_5,
  sum(s.same_day) same_day
from pre_5 p join after_5  a on a.creation_date = p.creation_date
                            and a.type = p.type
             join same_day s on s.creation_date = p.creation_date
                            and s.type = p.type
group by p.creation_date,
         p.type;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, adding my code back in and changing the joins gave me the data back in the way I wanted.